# How do you change the starting rotation on imported OBJ file?

Tags: import, transforms

When I import my obj file into Blender the rotation of the actual object is not correct (like when you look in *Transform > Rotation*; the X value is at 90 degrees while the others are at zero)

Do you know how to change this starting value so that my object is straight?

This has become an issue since the measurements in *Transform > Dimensions* are not correct since blender measures the object upon initial import and now after I rotate the object to it's proper orientations.

[image: picture of the rotation]

Comment: The initial rotation is determined by the original position of the object and application that exported that file. Either rotate it in the source application before exporting, or there's not much you can do afterwards besides manually fixing it. See the techniques described here http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33226/object-flips-while-snapping-to-another-object-with-align-rotation-using-face-sn or here http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46584/how-to-align-an-object-so-one-of-its-faces-are-axis-aligned-make-an-object-upr if this helps

Comment: Obj. import operation has parameters in the bottom left of the File Browser window where you can choose which axis Blender to interpet as up and which as forward. Maybe that could help ?